# SCRIPT errors with IE 11 when using Babel and Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer-11, babeljs

We're having a problem with our Vue.js application on Windows 10 / IE 11.

The application was giving `SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'` until we updated out `babel.config` to the following:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset',
      {
        targets: {
          'ie': '11'
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

At which point the error is now `SCRIPT1002: Synxax Error chunk-vendors.js (11365, 9311)` which appears to relate to the `vuelidate` node module.

It appears that I need to `exclude` the above package, but I dont understand where the syntax should go.
It's also likely that there will be multiple packages that I need to exclude.

The base project was built using `vue-cli 4.4.1` and the config files haven't moved far from the stock install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to transpile the modules? You could use `exclude` property in `webpack.config.js` or `babel.config.js` to transpile modules.

You could change this line:

```
...
 exclude: /node_modules/,
...
```

into this:

```
...
  exclude: /node_modules\/(?!name-of-untranspiled-module)/,
...
```

If you need to exclude more than one module you can extend the exception list like so:

```
exclude: /node_modules\/(?![module1|module2])/
```

For more information, you could refer to [this link](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/171).

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was looking for. Unfortunately that has not solved the errors that I was having.